CSS not applied to the extra part of overflow-x:
enter image description here
I am having a bug like in the picture, when  has many . To make the code responsive,  has overflow-x: auto, but the extra part is not applying css code of .
My JSX code:
<div className="profile-flights-list">
              <div className="profile-flights-list-row">
                <div className="profile-flights-column departure-time">Thời gian xuất phát</div>
                <div className="profile-flights-column arrival-time">Thời gian đến</div>
                <div className="profile-flights-column departure-location">
                  Địa điểm xuất phát
                </div>
                <div className="profile-flights-column arrival-location">Địa điểm đến</div>
                <div className="profile-flights-column passenger-info">Thông tin người bay</div>
                <div className="profile-flights-column ticket-info">Thông tin vé</div>
                <div className="profile-flights-column status">Trạng thái</div>
                <div className="profile-flights-column cancel">Hủy vé</div>
              </div>
            <div className="profile-flights-list-body">
            </div>


And the  has many 
My CSS code:
.profile-flights-list {
  margin: 1rem 1rem 1rem 1rem;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  overflow-x: auto; 
}

.profile-flights-list > .profile-flights-list-row:first-child {
  background-color: #cce1b1; 
  font-weight: 700; 
}
.profile-flights-list-row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(5rem, 2fr) minmax(5rem, 2fr) minmax(5rem, 2fr) minmax(5rem, 2fr) minmax(15rem, 6fr) minmax(7.5rem, 3fr) minmax(5rem, 2fr) minmax(2.5rem, 1fr);
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.profile-flights-list-row:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

Thanks for reading!, if you need anymore information, please let me know!
I am not too experienced in coding frontend for website so I haven't come up with any solution yet.

What do you mean by overflow-x 'the extra part is not applying css code of'?  Are you sure of what are you asking?  Please go through some CSS articles online and understand first.  According to me there is no width applied then how can there be overflow-x: auto will be applied.  Even if it applied, what actually you're trying to achieve?

Please add one or two rows of data to your table.

In your code, you can add the profile-flights-list to the overflow property so the child element of the profile-flights-list is the profile-flights-list-row, so that element does not apply to the full row element; it just only applies to the screen heading.
So apply the overflow property to the profile-flights-list-row so that all child elements apply to CSS when you scroll.


.profile-flights-list {
    margin: 1rem 1rem 1rem 1rem;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
}

.profile-flights-list>.profile-flights-list-row:first-child {
    background-color: #cce1b1;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.profile-flights-list-row {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: minmax(5rem, 2fr) minmax(5rem, 2fr) minmax(5rem, 2fr) minmax(5rem, 2fr) minmax(15rem, 6fr) minmax(7.5rem, 3fr) minmax(5rem, 2fr) minmax(2.5rem, 1fr);
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.profile-flights-list-row:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}
<div class="profile-flights-list">
    <div class="profile-flights-list-row">
        <div class="profile-flights-column departure-time">Thời gian xuất phát</div>
        <div class="profile-flights-column arrival-time">Thời gian đến</div>
        <div class="profile-flights-column departure-location">
            Địa điểm xuất phát
        </div>
        <div class="profile-flights-column arrival-location">Địa điểm đến</div>
        <div class="profile-flights-column passenger-info">Thông tin người bay</div>
        <div class="profile-flights-column ticket-info">Thông tin vé</div>
        <div class="profile-flights-column status">Trạng thái</div>
        <div class="profile-flights-column cancel">Hủy vé</div>
    </div>
    <div class="profile-flights-list-body">
    </div>
</div>




If you are concerned about the background color then give overflow-x: auto property to  .profile-flights-list-row class.
.profile-flights-list-row{
     display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: minmax(5rem, 2fr) minmax(5rem, 2fr) minmax(5rem, 2fr) minmax(5rem, 2fr) minmax(15rem, 6fr) minmax(7.5rem, 3fr) minmax(5rem, 2fr) minmax(2.5rem, 1fr);
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    flex-shrink: calc(0);
    ***overflow-x: auto;***
}

